# acts_as_list on has_many :through and sortablejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list

I have a fairly large question that I've been unable to resolve after a full day of reading articles, documentation and other Stack questions. At this point it's just messing with my mind!

I have an app that is Vue/Vuetify on the frontend with a data-table that I want to be able to reorder with sortablejs. On the backend, I have a Rails API that I'd like to use the acts_as_list gem to handle reordering for me.

*Ideally* I'd be able to call something like `Category.first.items.last.move_higher`, however because I have a join model I'm having to put `acts_as_list` and the position column on the join model instead of the Item model. Is there a better way to arrange this?

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_items
  has_many :items, through: :categories_items, source: :item

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items

end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_items
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_items, source: :category

end
```

**categories_item.rb**

```
class CategoriesItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :item

  acts_as_list scope: :category
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that structure you'll definitely need to reorder by calling methods on the join model. You can however use the Rails `delegate` class method to delegate reordering methods to the join model if you like:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

All of this assumes that you need `items` and `categories` to have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` type relationship.

Comment: Hmm ok, I suppose it's not a huge deal to have those gem methods available on the join rather than the Item model.

Comment: It seems to me to be actually quite correct. You're not reordering `items`, you're reordering the joins. You may even want to have a `CategoriesItemController` to manage the sorting actions.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry, my understanding of joins starts to get pretty foggy past surface-level, so any time I'm confronted with these more complex concepts I start having trouble with it. Thanks for taking the time!